# Self Studying Guide for applied math

Tags: probability, soft-question, self-learning

I'm an economics student passionate by math and statistics, however, I discovered this only now. I`m 19 and I really want to become very good in math, especially applied math and probability theory.

What advice can you give me to build a good self-study guide to follow and be able to reach my goal.

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are asking: You say you are passionate about math and statistics, so there should be topics and questions that interest you. I think the best way forward for you is to follow up on these, but that should be somewhat obvious. What would you expect a "self-study guide" to entail? The point of self study is that you can decide for yourself how you study.